'CreateProcess' failed to run
I am trying to create an R script which takes an input json and hit and endpoint on grpc server and returns the output but getting this 'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\anekuma\DOWNLO~1\GRPCUR~1.6_W\grpcurl.exe -plaintext -H "Authorization: Bearer <Bearer_Token>
My Script is
library(jsonlite)
address <- <Address:Port>
service_method <- "Package/Method"
json_message <- fromJSON("abc.json")
bearer_token <- <Bearer Token>
escaped_json_message <- gsub('"', '\\\\"', json_message)
grpcurl_cmd <- paste(
  'grpcurl -plaintext -H "Authorization: Bearer', bearer_token, '" -d', shQuote(escaped_json_message), address, service_method
)
grpcurl_cmd <- paste(grpcurl_cmd, collapse = " ")
cat("Type of grpcurl_cmd:", typeof(grpcurl_cmd), "\n")
cat("Length of grpcurl_cmd:", length(grpcurl_cmd), "\n")
cat("Running command:", grpcurl_cmd, "\n")
result <- system(grpcurl_cmd, intern = TRUE)

The script should return the output

Are you able to run the grpcurl command directly?

Yes in my cmd I am able to run
